# How can I processing subgroup data Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

am new to the Python, I have a data processing questions, I have a data frame like this: data sample

```
Group iD    name     date    origin_date
1          hshoff    8/7/13  8/7/13
1          hshoff    8/7/13  8/7/13
10         parolkar  1/8/14  1/8/14
10         davelester 1/9/14     1/9/14
100        ryw       5/3/16  5/3/16
100        haosdent  5/7/16  7/29/15
100        rukletsov 5/10/16 4/6/16
101        haosdent  5/7/16  7/29/15
101        haosdent  5/7/16  7/29/15
```

So as you could see there are 4 groups based on the group ID.

What I want is in each group, in the last column (origin date), I would like to use the each name's origin date to substract the first name's origin date. For example, in group 100, haosdent's origin date - ryw's origin date; rukletsov's origin date - ryw's origin date. So on and forth, if even one group has 100 names, it should alwasy minues the first name's origin date.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Convert your origin_date to datetime and then groupby and subtract

```
df['origin_date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['origin_date'])
df['new_col'] = df['origin_date'] - df.groupby('Group iD')['origin_date'].transform('first')

   Group iD        name     date origin_date   new_col
0         1      hshoff   8/7/13  2013-08-07    0 days
1         1      hshoff   8/7/13  2013-08-07    0 days
2        10    parolkar   1/8/14  2014-01-08    0 days
3        10  davelester   1/9/14  2014-01-09    1 days
4       100         ryw   5/3/16  2016-05-03    0 days
5       100    haosdent   5/7/16  2015-07-29 -279 days
6       100   rukletsov  5/10/16  2016-04-06  -27 days
7       101    haosdent   5/7/16  2015-07-29    0 days
8       101    haosdent   5/7/16  2015-07-29    0 days
```